# Syntax error, unexpected ´´usertype´´ <T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING>

Tags: php, syntax-error

As the title says, I get the error:

> Syntax error, unexpected ´´usertype´´  expecting ...... \AccountTableSeeder.php on line:12

My AccountTableSeeder:

```
<?php

class AccountTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('account')->delete();
        User::create(array(
            'name' => 'admin2',
            'passwd' => Hash::make('0x,admin')
            'usertype' => '1'
            'money' => '1000'
            'id' => '1'
            'email' => 'admin@example.com'
            'isTest' => ''
            'secretquestion' => ''
            'secretanswer' => ''
            'registerip' => '192.168.0.0'
            'regdate' => '2014-13-06 15:07:00.333'
        ));
    }

}
```

My create_account_table

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateAccountTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('account', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->char('name', 16)->unique();
            $table->string('passwd');
            $table->integer('usertype');
            $table->integer('money');
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->tinyInteger('isTest');
            $table->mediumText('secretquestion');
            $table->mediumText('secretanswer');
            $table->text('registerip');
            $table->dateTime('regdate');
            $table->unique( array('email','name','id') );
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::create('account', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            //
        });
    }

}
```

I tried to use the commane: php artisan db:seed
I hope you can help me :)

Comment: you forgot `,` after array elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing commas after your array values:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('account')->delete();
    User::create(array(
        'name' => 'admin2',
        'passwd' => Hash::make('0x,admin'),
        'usertype' => '1',
        'money' => '1000',
        'id' => '1',
        'email' => 'admin@example.com',
        'isTest' => '',
        'secretquestion' => '',
        'secretanswer' => '',
        'registerip' => '192.168.0.0',
        'regdate' => '2014-13-06 15:07:00.333'
    ));
}
```

FYI, a decent IDE would catch this for you and alert you of your error immediately.

Comment: Maybe OP thinks that if it works using JS syntax/convention, that it would in PHP; nope. ;-)

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I type `$array = new array()` in PHP I'd have a lot of dollars.

Comment: SO should start giving us a bonus every once in a while lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would take it in the form of pizza :)

Comment: Totally! Double mushroom, double olive of course ;-)

Comment: @user3665428 Do tick that little checkmark ;-) I like Green over white any day.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That would be far too freaky for me. I can do sausage or meatballs. After that, freakyland!

Comment: *Hm...* sounds good. Pepperoni's always a classic too.